# Error arises from simple query from sen2r R package

Tags: r, sentinel2, sen2r

I am trying to load some Sentinel satellite imagery using the `sen2r` R package and am having trouble. In short, even the simplest example from the documentation does not work. This example goes as follows:

```
json_path <- build_example_param_file()

if (is_gcloud_configured()) {
  out_paths_2 <- sen2r(json_path)
} else {
  out_paths_2 <- character(0)
}
```

This is the output I receive; some of it is messaging that appears to be nonimpactful to the outcome, and the error is a bit vague and seems to arise from a little big within some function the package is using.

```
[2023-12-04 17:59:26] #### Starting sen2r execution. ####
Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
[2023-12-04 17:59:27] Searching for available SAFE products...
old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
[2023-12-04 17:59:28] Querying Google Cloud (this can take a very long time)...
  |==========================================================================================| 100%Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
Spherical geometry (s2) switched on
```

The example code makes up a default .json file with arguments for the function. The contents of this file are as follows:

```
{
  "preprocess": [true],
  "s2_levels": ["l1c", "l2a"],
  "sel_sensor": ["s2a", "s2b"],
  "online": [true],
  "server": ["gcloud"],
  "order_lta": [true],
  "downloader": ["builtin"],
  "overwrite_safe": [false],
  "rm_safe": ["no"],
  "max_cloud_safe": [100],
  "step_atmcorr": ["l2a"],
  "sen2cor_use_dem": [null],
  "sen2cor_gipp": [null],
  "timewindow": ["2020-08-01", "2020-08-01"],
  "timeperiod": ["full"],
  "extent": ["C:/Users/pthom/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/sen2r/extdata/vector/barbellino.geojson"],
  "s2tiles_selected": [null],
  "s2orbits_selected": [null],
  "list_prods": ["BOA", "SCL"],
  "list_indices": ["MSAVI2", "NDVI"],
  "list_rgb": ["RGB432B", "RGB843B"],
  "rgb_ranges": [
    [0, 2500],
    [
      [0, 7500],
      [0, 2500],
      [0, 2500]
    ]
  ],
  "index_source": ["BOA"],
  "mask_type": [null],
  "max_mask": [100],
  "mask_smooth": [0],
  "mask_buffer": [0],
  "clip_on_extent": [true],
  "extent_as_mask": [false],
  "extent_name": ["sen2r"],
  "reference_path": [null],
  "res": [null],
  "res_s2": ["10m"],
  "unit": ["Meter"],
  "proj": [null],
  "resampling": ["near"],
  "resampling_scl": ["near"],
  "outformat": ["GTiff"],
  "rgb_outformat": ["GTiff"],
  "index_datatype": ["Int16"],
  "compression": ["DEFLATE"],
  "rgb_compression": ["DEFLATE"],
  "overwrite": [false],
  "path_l1c": ["C:/Users/pthom/DOCUME~1/SEN2R~1/safe"],
  "path_l2a": ["C:/Users/pthom/DOCUME~1/SEN2R~1/safe"],
  "path_tiles": [null],
  "path_merged": [null],
  "path_out": ["C:\\Users\\pthom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpyAjAd3\\sen2r_out_120814e04eb2"],
  "path_rgb": [""],
  "path_indices": [""],
  "path_subdirs": [true],
  "thumbnails": [true],
  "log": [null],
  "parallel": [false],
  "processing_order": ["by_groups"],
  "pkg_version": ["1.6.0"]
}
```

To identify a spatial extent for the query this file calls on a geoJSON file provided by the `sen2r` package. The contents of this file are displayed here.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "barbellino",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32632" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 580560.0, 5101700.0 ], [ 580680.0, 5101700.0 ], [ 580800.0, 5101820.0 ], [ 580800.0, 5102120.0 ], [ 580660.0, 5102120.0 ], [ 580560.0, 5102020.0 ], [ 580560.0, 5101700.0 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I am using R 4.3.2 and sen2r version 1.6.0. I have tried updating all installed R packages on my device, installing sen2r using `install_github`, and looking through lots of other similar issues online. It may be just that the issue cannot be fixed unless the creator of the package is able to restore something; I'm not sure. It appears that the package has been updated recently to reflect some non-R software changes, so most of the questions about `sen2r` online come from older versions. Let me know if there's any other information you would find helpful, or if you have any suggestions for me here.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed the package was changed recently since the old Copernicus scihub API was deprecated, and the original maintainer can no longer answer questions.  Are you sure you have images in the date range/cloud cover that you specified?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. The code I ran above makes a .json file with default parameters. Maybe there is a problem with these. I have edited my question to include the contents of this file. For what it's worth `sen2r()` also fails for me when I try to generate a custom query meeting my own needs, but I figured it'd be easier to sort the problem out with a more easily reproducible example. Let me know if this gives you any ideas and thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You have only one single date in your time range: "2022-08-01".

Set to something like:

```
"timewindow": ["2020-07-01", "2020-09-01"]
```

and try again.

**Edits...**

I copied your config.json, and the geojson extent file from above, into a directory on my computer, and ran the `sen2r` command as follows (overwriting some of the config options, to simplify):

```
library(sen2r)    
sen2r(param_list = "~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/config.json", gui = FALSE, timewindow = c('2020-07-01', '2020-09-01'), rm_safe = "no", extent = "~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/aoi.geojson", extent_name = "barbellino", path_l1c = "~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/", path_l2a = "~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/", path_out = "~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/", overwrite_safe = FALSE, list_prods = "BOA", list_indices = "SAVI")
list.files("~/work/tmp/PeterThompson/BOA", pattern = ".*tif")
 [1] "S2A2A_20200707_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200710_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
 [3] "S2A2A_20200717_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200720_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
 [5] "S2A2A_20200727_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200730_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
 [7] "S2A2A_20200806_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200809_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
 [9] "S2A2A_20200816_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200819_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[11] "S2A2A_20200826_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2A2A_20200829_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[13] "S2B2A_20200702_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200705_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[15] "S2B2A_20200712_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200715_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[17] "S2B2A_20200722_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200725_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[19] "S2B2A_20200801_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200804_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[21] "S2B2A_20200811_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200814_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[23] "S2B2A_20200821_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif" "S2B2A_20200824_065_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
[25] "S2B2A_20200831_022_barbellino_BOA_10.tif"
```

This code successfully downloaded 25 SAFE directories, and created the BOA and SAVI products.

Perhaps you can start with something simple, then if it works, try adding other products.

Comment: Ah - good catch - I changed it and still gives the same error, though. I also tried removing or changing all the arguments in the JSON file that are currently set to `null`, since the error message appears to arise from an R `NULL` object. But still no luck. Any other suggestions are welcome; thanks for your responses!

Comment: Can you share your AOI file, and the full json config?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the contents of the AOI file, which is stored as a GeoJSON. I didn't make this file; it's provided by the `sen2r` package, but it looks reasonable to me at a quick glance. That being said, I'm not experienced with this sort of stuff, and I may ask for a clarification on what you mean by the "full json config". Is that a separate file that's made as part of the process, or are you just looking for the new version of the JSON file I already posted with some of the `null` values removed?

Comment: I tried with your config.json and your aoi file, but with a somewhat simpler configs. See the edited answer above.